# How to clear out all sharp edges

Tags: add-on, 3d-printing

I have a brain stl model extracted from cbct. Like the picture [image: 1] .

I have run edge sharp analysis of 3d print toolbox. Like in the
[image: 2] .

As you can see, I got many warnings.

To do operation on the sharp edges, I have only selected the sharp edges out of the brain model.

1. I did smooth modifier with 100 but the warning is same.
   [image: 3]
2. And after that, I have run smooth tool in the left hand side of the blender. But nothing changed.
   [image: 4]

Question:
How to clear out or smooth all sharp edges?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you've selected all the sharp edges using the button in the 3D Print Toolbox in `EDIT MODE`

[image]

...hit `ctrl-b` to bevel them and drag your mouse a bit. Make sure `Clamp Overlap` is selected so you don't create any overlapping faces. Then select everything with `a` and `Mesh -> Clean Up -> Merge by Distance`

[image]

Honestly though, not sure why you'd even care if your 3D printing it, your slicer resolution should just round them off.

Comment: I dont want to smooth all of the object. I just smooth the selected edges via button on the 3d prşnt toolbox. Your answer works on object mode but not in edit mode. I have tried to separate the sharp edges then belvel and try to merge but nothing changed.

Comment: This should ONLY work in edit mode. Clicking the `Sharp Edge` result in the 3D Print Toolbox while in edit mode will select only the sharp edges, then you can bevel as instructed. Perhaps it was unclear... I'll edit for clarity.

Comment: After selecting the sharp edges and then making them as sharp, does it help me before using bevel edge?

Comment: No... See here https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/edge/edge_data.html#mark-sharp-clear-sharp